# Как из html-кода страницы в Instagram вывести id аккаунта?

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api

Я знаю, как получить id через инструменты разработчика: f12 -> ctrl+f -> "id". Необходимая информация будет содержаться в словаре следующего вида:

```
{"id": "1234567890", "username": "user007"}
```

Как эту же информацию получить с помощью python?

Использовала следующий код:

```
import urllib
import requests

f = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.instagram.com/user007/").read()
output = f.decode('utf-8')
print(output)
```

Но в выводе не было нужной информации.

P.S. user007 - выдуманное имя пользователя

Comment: Вы вывели страницу в консоль `print(output)` и там не было того id, который ожидали?

Comment: не было, почему то в output не вся информация включается, либо она каким то образом еще кодируется

Comment: Возможно, она js добавляется

Comment: извините, не поняла про что вы

Comment: Кст, для вашей ссылке нашлось в браузере: `"owner":{"id":"8079564","username":"user007"}`. Но проверить кодом не удалось, т.к. инстаграм отвечал редиректом к https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/user007/, чтобы сначала сделал авторизацию, а на странице по редиректу не было того id юзера. Проверял через `requests`: `import requests` `rs = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/user007/')` `print(rs.url)` `print('"owner":{"id":"8079564"' in rs.text)`

Comment: Я бы попробовал поработать через API, библиотеки на питоне для этого есть